# How do I call a selector on NSObject without casting it to the original object?

Tags: objective-c

I've implemented a function that posts data to a webservice. When I need to send different types of data I've created the selctor like this:

```
- (void)postRequest:(NSString *)service toEndpoint:(NSString*)endpoint withParams:(NSObject *)params
```

How do I run a method on the params object when I don't know whtat kind of object it is?
currentlig I've implemented a test - cast scenario for each type that I'm posting, but that is a bad way to implement this...
Like this:

```
if([params isKindOfClass:[Order class]]){
  Order *order = (Order *) params;
  jsonString = [order objectToDictionary];
}
```

I've experimented with:

```
if ([params respondsToSelector:@selector(objectToDictionary:)]) {
  jsonString = [params objectToDictionary];
}
```

But that seems impossible without casting *params* to the right type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also you may use a subclass of `NSObject` something like `ParametersObject` and asure that all your objects that are going to be sent on the withParams argument inherit from this class.

This class must to implement all the selectors that you need like `objectToDictionary:` for example.

Comment: Well naturally. I'm using KVCBaseObject. I should have used that as paramater instead of NSObject.

Comment: Yes, you should. And that is.

Answer (score 3):

use `id` type. `id` is a special keyword used in Objective-C to mean “some kind of object.”

```
- (void)postRequest:(NSString *)service toEndpoint:(NSString*)endpoint withParams:(id)params
```

Comment: Thank you, you've taught me somehting new today. I choose to use D33pN16h7's solution below. I didn't think through what I was sending and used the parent->parent class instead of the direct parent class of the objects I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

Make all your objects that get sent in the request conform to the same protocol. Then you can define the method signature as follows:

```
- (void)postRequest:(NSString *)service toEndpoint:(NSString*)endpoint withParams:(id<YourPostRequestProtocol>)params;
```

And then in `YourPostRequestProtocol` you can define the method

```
- (NSDictionary *)objectToDictionary;
```

And each object, e.g. `Order`, can conform to that protocol and implement that method.

```
@interface Order : NSObject<YourPostRequestProtocol>

@end

@implementation

- (NSDictionary *)objectToDictionary
{
   // The implementation for this object
}

@end
```

Comment: This seems like a clean solution, I will keep this in mind :-)